# how to distinguish between multiple NSXMLParser in NSOperationQueue

Tags: cocoa, nsxmlparser, nsoperationqueue

I have multiple `NSXMLParser` in `NSOperationQueue`. When the `NSXMLParser` call `parserDidEndDocument` I need to distinguish between thous parsers. I thought I could use something like `userInfo` but there is nothing like that. Is there some way to distinguish the parsers?

EDIT: Thous parsers have same delegate for caling `parserDidEndDocument`

CONCLUSION:

```
@interface MyParser : NSXMLParser
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *action;
@end

@implementation MyParser
@synthesize action=_action;
@end
```

Comment: Is there another way to do such specialization? Just to add another property to class NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to conclusion that the best way is specialize the `NSXMLParser`.

```
@interface MyParser : NSXMLParser
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *action;
@end

@implementation MyParser
@synthesize action=_action;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you'll see that the parser itself is passed as the sole parameter of that method, so the easy way to distinguish them is to simply check what parser got passed.

In order for that to work, you'll probably have to keep references to the parsers you create for future reference, but that is not necessarily a bad idea, generally.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got already another idea. I created my class which specialize the `NSXMLParser` and have property for the distinguishing.

Answer (score 1):

An NSOperation subclass can post its own notifications. Some other class just needs to register as an observer.

Comment: This is good option as well. But I think specialization looks beter :).